# Как задать перечисление в php?

Tags: php

Пытаюсь создать мультилендинг на php, есть шесть так называемых шаблонов (египет,бали,араб-эмираты,греция,вьетнам,по умолчанию) подскажите пожалуйста, как задать перечисление этих самых utm меток? чтобы каждый раз не прописывать одно и тоже.

Т.е там где например "египет" добавить "Отдых в египте"

```html
<?php
$utm = $_GET['utm_content'];

if($utm == 'египет') {
 $multiTitle = '<h2 class="h2">Отдых в <span>Египте</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>340$ </span>с человека</h2>';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/egypt.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Египет';
}
elseif($utm == 'бали') {
 $multiTitle = 'Отдых на <span>Бали</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>413$</span> с человека';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/bali.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Бали';
}
elseif($utm == 'арабские-эмираты') {
 $multiTitle = 'Отдых в <span>Арабских Эмиратах</span> на 7 ночей от  <span>413$</span> с человека';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/arabic-emiratec.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Арабские Эмираты';
}
elseif($utm == 'греция') {
 $multiTitle = 'Отдых в <span>Греции</span> на 7 ночей <br>от <span>511&euro;</span> с человека';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/grecia.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Грецию';
}
elseif($utm == 'вьетнам') {
 $multiTitle = 'Отдых во <span>Вьетнаме</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>413$</span> с человека';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/vietnam.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур во Вьетнам';
}
else{
 $multiTitle = '<span>Ранее</span> бронирование <br> туров в любые страны!';
 $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/6.jpg';
 $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на ранее бронирование';
}
?>
```

Comment: `in_array` или `preg_match`

Comment: Вариант 'хранить в базе' не рассматривается? Я не сторонник хранить такие вещи в коде, хардкодить -- плохой вариант как по мнк, потом только программист сможет поменять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Switch

Ручное наполнение условий, не особо, но читаемый код:

```
switch(mb_strtolower($utm)) {
    case 'египет':
    case 'отдых в египте':
        $multiTitle = '<h2 class="h2">Отдых в <span>Египте</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>340$ </span>с человека</h2>';
        $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/egypt.jpg';
        $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Египет';
        break;
    case 'бали':
        $multiTitle = 'Отдых на <span>Бали</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>413$</span> с человека';
        $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/bali.jpg';
        $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Бали';
        break;
    default:
        $multiTitle = '<span>Ранее</span> бронирование <br> туров в любые страны!';
        $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/6.jpg';
        $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на ранее бронирование';
        break;
}
```

## preg_match

Это как ваш текущий if, только расширенный

```
if(preg_match('/(египет|отдых в египте)/iu', $utm) {
    $multiTitle = '<h2 class="h2">Отдых в <span>Египте</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>340$ </span>с человека</h2>';
    $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/egypt.jpg';
    $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Египет';
}
elseif(preg_match('/(бали|отдых на бали)/iu', $utm)) {
    $multiTitle = 'Отдых на <span>Бали</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>413$</span> с человека';
    $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/bali.jpg';
    $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на тур в Бали';
}
else{
    $multiTitle = '<span>Ранее</span> бронирование <br> туров в любые страны!';
    $multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/6.jpg';
    $multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на ранее бронирование';
}
```

## foreach in_array

Массивный способ, но он позволяет хранить и работать с данными динамически. К примеру можно выгрузить информацию в .json файл или в БД.

```
$multi_landing = [
    [
        'utm' => [
            'египет',
            'отдых в египте'
        ],
        'title' => '<h2 class="h2">Отдых в <span>Египте</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>340$ </span>с человека</h2>',
        'header-bg' => 'img/header-slider/egypt.jpg',
        'input-hidden' => 'Заявка на тур в Египет'
    ], [
        'utm' => [
            'бали',
            'отдых на бали'
        ],
        'title' => 'Отдых на <span>Бали</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>413$</span> с человека',
        'header-bg' => 'img/header-slider/bali.jpg',
        'input-hidden' => 'Заявка на тур в Бали'
    ]
];

$mark = mb_strtolower($utm);
$multiTitle = '<span>Ранее</span> бронирование <br> туров в любые страны!';
$multiHeaderBg = 'img/header-slider/6.jpg';
$multiInputHidden = 'Заявка на ранее бронирование';
foreach($multi_landing as $option) {
    if(in_array($mark, $option['utm'])) {
        $multiTitle = $option['title'];
        $multiHeaderBg = $option['header-bg'];
        $multiInputHidden = $option['input-hidden'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Храните данные в массиве:

```
$utms = [
    'египет' => [
        'title' => '<h2 class="h2">Отдых в <span>Египте</span> на 7 ночей <br> от  <span>340$ </span>с человека</h2>',
        'header-bg' => 'img/header-slider/egypt.jpg',
        'input-hidden' => 'Заявка на ранее бронирование',
    ],

    'бали' => [
        // наполнение для "бали"
    ],

    // и так далее
];
```

Для общего случая можно придумать какой-нибудь особый ключ массива. Например, `default`.

Тогда код обработки данных станет более общим:

```
$utm = $_GET['utm_content'];

if (!array_key_exists($utm, $utms)) {
    $utm = 'default';
}

$multiTitle = $utms[$utm]['title'];
$multiHeaderBg = $utms[$utm]['header-bg'];
$multiInputHidden = $utms[$utm['input-hidden'];
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ, не совсем то что нужно. в вашем варианте все же нужно для каждой метки прописывать одни и те же параметры, а мне например для "египта" и "отдыха в египте" нужен один и тот же ключ. т.е повторять ключ массива для нескольких меток.

Comment: @МихаилЗахаров, подскажите, как Вы представляете себе объявление подобных структурированных данных в плоском файле без "прописывания одних и тех же параметров"? Может быть сможете привести примеры из других языков программирования, чтобы мы поняли, что Вы подразумеваете под "перечислением"? Хочется понять, что ожидаете получить.

Comment: возможно я не правильно выражаюсь, мне нужно что-то наподобии javascript var arr = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];

Comment: @МихаилЗахаров, но ведь в том-то и дело, что у Вас не просто набор данных. У Вас набор **структурированных** данных. Вы не могли бы добавить пример, где каждому фрукту соответствует, например, размер и цвет. Яблоко зелёное большое, апельсин оранжевый маленький, а груша жёлтая огромная.